# Display data in ng-grid based on condition

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-grid

I have the display the data in ng-grid only if certain conditions are met.I thought of using filteroptions.I am a newbie to angularjs.So I am not sure how to do that.

my jsfile:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
$scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
                 {field:'age', displayName:'Age'}]
    };
```

});

And my htmlfile:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">  
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Getting Started With ngGrid Example</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ng-grid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ng-grid-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</body>
```

My requirement is want to display the record in html only if the age is greater than 30.

Comment: You're literally asking for the example under "row templates" on the [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/).

Comment: Dude in that example they changed the color of the rows on certain condition.But here i am trying to hide the row in the row template.I just used it an example thats it !!!